# Pandas object has no attribute even though I'm using exact column name

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to import excel file into MSSQL docker image, currently have this script giving me some pandas error yet I don't see what exactly could be wrong with it. Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

# Import CSV
data = pd.read_excel (r"C:\Users\c.stembridge\OneDrive - NEWREST GROUP SERVICES\Overtime Forecast Report.xlsx", sheet_name='Daily Hrs2')   
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Connect to SQL Server
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;UID=SA;PWD=Working@2022;DATABASE=testdb;Encrypt=no;TrustServerCertificate=yes")
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Create Table
cursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE Overtime_Forecast (
            date nvarchar(10) primary key,
            day nvarchar(9),
            hrs int,
            dl int,
            catered int,
            hrs_diff_btwn_last_day int,
            catered_flight_diff int,
            employees_OT_count int,
            carriers int,
            whole int,
            half int,
            total_carts int
            )
               ''')

# Insert DataFrame to Table
for row in df.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO Overtime_Forecast (
                        date nvarchar(10) primary key,
            day nvarchar(9),
            hrs int,
            dl int,
            catered int,
            hrs_diff_btwn_last_day int,
            catered_flight_diff int,
            employees_OT_count int,
            carriers int,
            whole int,
            half int,
            total_carts int)
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                ''',
                row.Date,
                row.Day,
                row.Hrs,
                row.DL,
                row.Catered,
                row.Hrs_diff_btwn_last_day,
                row.Catered_flight_diff,
                row.Employees_OT_count,
                row.Carriers,
                row.Whole,
                row.Half,
                row.Total_carts
                )
conn.commit()
```

My excel column header name is exactly "Hrs_diff_btwn_last_day" but console is telling me ```
row.Hrs_diff_btwn_last_day,
AttributeError: 'Pandas' object has no attribute 'Hrs_diff_btwn_last_day'

```
My excel column names here : Date, Day, Hrs, DL, Catered, Hrs_diff_btwn_last_day, Catered_flight_diff,  Employees_OT_count, Carriers, Whole, Half, Total_carts
```

Comment: You posted your excel column names, but what about `df.columns`? Have you checked for leading/trailing spaces? Have you tried directly accessing `df['Hrs_diff_btwn_last_day']`?

Comment: Yes @G.Anderson and still doesn't work, I tried using the strip method

Answer (score 0):

maybe because the existing column is hrs_diff_btwn_last_day instead of Hrs_diff_btwn_last_day